# Excel VB Filepath Concatenation not Working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in an Excel xlsm file designed to open and close a number of csv files within a certain folder while extracting information from them. The following is representative of the code:

```
Dim wbPath As String
Dim PathTextPart2 As String
Dim FName As String

PathTextPart2 = 123456
wbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path  '="H:\Folder"
FName = Dir(wbPath & "\" & PathTextPart2 & "PathTextPart3*.csv")
Workbooks.Open (FName)
```

The macro fails because FName returns "123456PathTextPart3789.csv", somehow leaving off "H:\Folder\" at the beginning of the string.  I have searched for solutions to my problem, but did not find any.  Can anyone spot what the problem is?

Comment: no inbuilt full path return feature in `Dir`. Just use `Workbooks.Open (wbPath & "\" & FName)`

Comment: I have checked your code and indeed Excel didn't assign anything to `wbPath`. The way it could be fixed is to save the file, which is logical - there is no path to an unsaved file.

Comment: @Devman have you tested any of the code you got as answers below ? any feedback ?

Comment: @Shai Rado; Yes, cyboashu's answer above works and your answer below also works.  Many thanks to both of you!

Comment: So mark either one of the answers as "answer", by clicking the **V** next to their answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant to loop through all files in Folder "H:\Folder\123456" use the code below.

**Note**: I've added a criteria test `Like "*.csv"`, this will only open files with ".csv" extension.

**Code**

```
Sub LoopCSVFiles()

Dim wbPath As String
Dim PathTextPart2 As String
Dim FName As String

PathTextPart2 = 123456
wbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & PathTextPart2 & "\" ' "H:\Folder"\123456\"
FName = Dir(wbPath)

' loop through all files in folder
Do Until FName = ""
    If FName Like "*.csv" Then ' only open files with .csv extension
        Workbooks.Open (FName)
        ' put the rest of your code here

    End If
    FName = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dir()` does not return the path part:

```
Sub dural()
    fname = Dir("C:\Users\garys\desktop\*.*")
    MsgBox fname
End Sub
```

[image]